# embedded neo4j database with tomcat 7.0 eclipse plugin Unable to create directory path for Neo4j store

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm using an embedded neo4j Database and everything works fine when I run a main in my java code. But if I try to connect to the database with a servlet on my tomcat plugin in eclipse there is this error:

```
Unable to create directory path [database\data\graph.db] for Neo4j store
```

My databse is stored in my javaproject. I'm pretty sure it's because the tomcat-plugin needs another path but I'm new to this kind of stuff and hope that someone can tell me whats the right path or show me a tutorial.

greetings

Comment: How do you initialize your Neo4j database?

Comment: graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

Comment: perhaps point DB_PATH to a directory that you have actually write permissions fro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your current working directory, and verify that you have permissions to create files there.   You can get your current working directory via the java `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

When you're running under tomcat inside of eclipse, sometimes the directory will be somewhere different than you expect, because it depends on many aspects of how you configured tomcat and eclipse.  So the first order of business is to figure out where exactly you're trying to write to.  Then verify that your user has permission to write to that directory, and that the directory/file doesn't already exist/isn't marked read-only.

Answer (score -1):

Run Eclipse as Administrator, it should work then.

Comment: It probably does work, but this is terrible advice. You shouldn't run anything as administrator unless the program specifically needs to do something that requires elevated access (installers etc.) and this is not one of those cases.